# Convert json data to javascript array - in multi-dimensional sense

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

I have a json array say

```
{
   "People": {
       "Person": [
          {"FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith"}
          {"FirstName": "Joe", "LastName": "Bloggs"}
          {"FirstName": "Wendy", "LastName": "Deng"}
        ]
    }
}
```

And I want to convert this into a `javascript` array (something like this)

```
var persons = [ ["FirstName", "John", "LastName", "Smith"], ["FirstName", "Joe", "LastName", "Bloggs"], ["FirstName", "Wendy", "LastName": "Deng"] ];
```

How do I accomplish this?  Hope my question makes sense and I realise the javascript array initialization may not be the correct way to put it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why not just use the JSON as a JavaScript object?

Comment: Two reasons: 1. It's out of my curiosity if there's any good array-like data structures that I can use to perform data manipulation inside the json such as binary search, binary sort etc versus javascript object. 2. I'm still a JSON newbie.

Comment: First of all, `JSON` is a data interchange format, represented as a string. `JSON` format can be mapped _directly_ to JavaScript types, including `Object` and `Array`. You question doesn't go into _why_ you want to do this, and maybe that would help you to understand the uses of JSON and JavaScript objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsfiddle demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/umeshpatil86/qLypg/)

```
var src={
   "People": {
       "Person": [
          {"FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Smith"},
          {"FirstName": "Joe", "LastName": "Bloggs"},
          {"FirstName": "Wendy", "LastName": "Deng"}
        ]
    }
};

var persons=[];
var obj=src["People"]["Person"];
for(i in obj){
  var temp=[];
  temp.push("FirstName");
  temp.push(obj[i].FirstName);
  temp.push("LastName");
  temp.push(obj[i].LastName);
  persons.push(temp);
  }

// persons contain your requried array
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll give it go and try it on my experimentation.  Cheers!

Comment: @AW-GWTF899, Well ! json is such data structure that you can play around however you wish :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do doesn't make alot of sense. Converting an existing valid JSON Object into the array format you specified is rather pointless, and will make accessing elements difficult.

Sounds like what you really want to do is this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString); // Your JSON, parsed into a JS object.
var persons = []
data.people.person.foEach( function(el) {
  person.push(el.FirstName + " " + el.LastName);
}
```

Now `persons` look like this:

```
["John Smith", "Joe Bloggs", "Wendy Deng"]
```

Are you sure you know how JSON and JavaScript objects work?

```
var myJSON = '{ "foo": { "bar": { "baz" : [1,2,3] } } }' // JSON, String type.
var myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON); // Now a JS Object type.
var innerArray = myObj.foo.bar.baz;
```

Now the value of variable `innerArray` is `[1,2,3]`, an `Array` type.

```
console.log(innerArray[0]); // Log the first element.

> 1 // First element is 1
```

Comment: Well, actually the example I provided above is a rough sketch which I just made up on the spot.  The actual example I wanted is lot of more (and complex)data of json and I want to extract certain elements in json that I'm more interested in to put in another array.

Comment: @AW-GWTF899 - And is it your intention to store the _keys_ as strings in the nested array as in your example? Because they will be the same for each object in the array, which seems a bit useless to me.

Comment: {"responseData": "translatedText":"\u6211"},"responseDetails":"","responseStatus":200,"matches":[{"id":"175389268","segment":"I","translation":"\u6211","quality":"74","reference":"","usage-count":2,"subject":"Social_Science","created-by":"UN","last-updated-by":null,"create-date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","last-update-date":"2010-11-13 15:05:19","match":1},{"id":"430922621","segment":"I.","translation":"I.","quality":"74","reference":"","usage-count":26,"subject":"All","created-by":"","last-updated-by":null,"create-date":"2012-08-17 13:09:06","last-update-date":"2012-08-17 13:09:06","match":1}}

Comment: Here's my example json data.  Basically what I want from this data is to pick the "matches"'s array elements store in another array as keys and i want to ignore the rest of the elements in the json data.  Just the matches key part, if that makes sense..

Comment: @AW-GWTF899 - It isn't even valid JSON.

Comment: I must have missed a few characters out in the json when I copied and pasted in the comment.  Also I had to readjust the content in the comments of because of its character limit.

Comment: @AW-GWTF899 - Ok well I made some edits to my answer, maybe that will help you.

Comment: Thanks.  You've been a great help!